# Why is my code displaying the same output every time?

Tags: java, file-io

I am supposed to end up with code that displays a flower's name and whether it grows in the sun or the shade. I was given 2 files. The file I am supposed to take the data from is called flowers.dat and includes the following data:

```
Astilbe
Shade
Marigold
Sun
Begonia
Sun
Primrose
Shade
Cosmos
Sun
Dahlia
Sun
Geranium 
Sun
Foxglove
Shade
Trillium
Shade
Pansy
Sun
Petunia
Sun
Daisy
Sun
Aster
Sun
```

I have come up with this code

```
// Flowers.java - This program reads names of flowers and whether they are grown in shade or sun from an input 
// file and prints the information to the user's screen. 
// Input:  flowers.dat.
// Output: Names of flowers and the words sun or shade.

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;

public class Flowers {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        // Declare variables here
        String flowerName, flowerPosition;

        // Open input file.
        FileReader fr = new FileReader("flowers.dat");
        // Create BufferedReader object.
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        flowerName = br.readLine();
        flowerPosition = br.readLine();

        // Write while loop that reads records from file.
        while ((flowerName = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(flowerName + " is grown in the " + flowerPosition);
        }

        br.close();
        System.exit(0);
    } // End of main() method.

} // End of Flowers class.
```

The output that I am getting displays everything as growing in the shade. For instance, it says "Marigold is grown in the Shade. Sun is grown in the Shade" and so on. What am I missing?

Comment: You only set flowerPosition once, and the print the same value each time through your loop.  Why would you expect it to print a different value each time?

Comment: How do I change that? I wasn't taught how to set it more than once

Comment: You are already reading separate lines into each variable to initialize prior to your loop.  You just need to do something similar inside your loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you're doing is *reprinting* the variable.

```
System.out.println(flowerName + " is grown in the " + flowerPosition);
```

Rework your loop so you can always get those values read in.

```
do {
    flowerName = br.readLine();
    if(flowerName == null) {
        break;
    }
    flowerPosition = br.readLine();
    System.out.println(flowerName + " is grown in the " + flowerPosition);
} while(true);
```

Comment: Oh ok! Thank you. I see now. The original code was the way I was taught but it doesn't work...